# Can't coordinate the correct time between system and rtcwake

Tags: time, date

The ultimate goal is to have my system shut off at the end of a script and wake up at a defined time the next day.  I'm using `rtcwake` to get this done, like so (I am also printing the date and time to the output just for comparison)

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -l -t $(date -d "21:00 today" +"%s") -n
```

whose output is

```
Mon Sep 18 20:59:12 EDT 2017
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Mon Sep 18 17:00:00 2017
```

So, although the date and time returned by `/bin/date` are correct, and I (think that I) am setting the wakeup time for 21:00, `rtcwake` is interpreting the time as 17:00, 4 hours prior.  (I realize that I am setting it to wake up the same day here.  I want to get it working and then alter it to wake up the next day.)

To troubleshoot I altered the script a bit, removing the defined time, to read

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -l -t $(date +"%s") -n
```

which gave the output

```
Mon Sep 18 21:14:46 EDT 2017
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Mon Sep 18 17:14:46 2017
```

which is again 4 hours prior to the actual time.  This made me think that `date` doesn't have the correct time.  But when I altered the script to remove the `-l` option from the `rtcwake` command

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -t $(date +"%s") -n
```

the output was

```
Mon Sep 18 21:18:04 EDT 2017
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Tue Sep 19 01:18:04 2017
```

which is now 4 hours after the current time.  The 4 hour difference doesn't make sense to me, as I am on EDT (New York) and UTC is a 5 hour difference.

I played around some more and got the following:

1.

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -t $(date +"%s" -d "tomorrow 10:00") -n

Mon Sep 18 21:19:11 EDT 2017
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Tue Sep 19 14:00:00 2017
```

2.

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off --date tomorrow 10:00 -n

Mon Sep 18 21:20:55 EDT 2017
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Tue Sep 19 04:00:00 2017
```

3

```
/bin/date
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -l --date tomorrow 10:00 -n

Mon Sep 18 21:21:16 EDT 2017
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Mon Sep 18 20:00:00 2017
```

In conclusion:
I think that `rtcwake` doesn't actually know what time it is, though I can't be sure that I'm even entering my wakeup date and time properly.  I've opened the `rtcwake` and `date` manuals countless times, but I'm not seeing my issue.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have personally tested myself.

To test that I simply did "sudo rtcwake -m disk -s 60" , which simply hibernated it and waked it up after 1mins.

Thing here to note is that rctwake uses UTC and not your local time if not specified.

So now instead you need to sync your clock with your current time,then based on the difference change your  "etc/adjtime" using sudo mode and change according to the difference.

In my case I use IST which is +5:30 i.e 5 hours 30 min ahead so I wrote "5:30"  in the adjtime file.

Now If I use "sudo rtcwake --local -m disk -s 60"  command it shows my IST time instead of the previous UTC time.

So from now you need to add "--local" or "-l" option too  as mentioned in the manpage.

Example :  "sudo rtcwake --local -m no -l -t $(date +%s -d ‘tomorrow 09:30’)"

would wake your system the next day at 9:30 am as per your local time from /dev/rtc0. After this you can set up a cron to set this up automatically.

Sources: [rtcwake man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake)   , [from how to geek, some more configs](https://www.howtogeek.com/121241/how-to-make-your-linux-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue (`rtcwake` was using a different time than the "local" time), but after reading about the `timedatectl` command [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181010173429/http://www.linuxfromscratch.org:80/lfs/view/systemd/chapter07/clock.html) I eventually realized my timezone was incorrect.

I set the timezone with this command:

```
timedatectl set-timezone MYTIMEZONE
```

After that `rtcwake` uses the correct time, even with the default settings (no need for me to specify `--local`.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Sapphire_Brick, link is fixed now.